# Python recvfrom works on Windows but not Linux

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking, udp

There's a TI radar device that uses a static Ethernet interface that I wrote a Python script to test. When the device receives the message sent from this script, it responds with another message that shows up on Wireshark on both Windows and Linux. However, even though the recvfrom function returns with the data on Windows, it times out on Linux (I tried it on a Linux Mint laptop and a Raspberry Pi). I tried adding a variety of rules to firewall using ufw too, such as "sudo ufw allow from 192.168.33.180", but it still times out. Here's the code:

```
import socket
import codecs

cmd = '0100'
CONFIG_HEADER = '5aa5'
CONFIG_FOOTER = 'aaee'
length='0000'
body=''
msg = codecs.decode(''.join((CONFIG_HEADER, str(cmd), length, body, CONFIG_FOOTER)), 'hex')
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                    socket.SOCK_DGRAM,
                    socket.IPPROTO_UDP)

sock.settimeout(10)
sock.bind(('192.168.33.30', 4096))
send = (msg, ('192.168.33.180', 4096))
sock.sendto(send[0], send[1])
print(send)
recv = sock.recvfrom(4096)
print(recv)
```

Here's the result of running the code on Windows:

```
PS C:\ti\AWR1243-Capture> python .\python\test.py
(b'Z\xa5\x01\x00\x00\x00\xaa\xee', ('192.168.33.180', 4096))
(b'Z\xa5\x01\x00\x00\x00\xaa\xee', ('192.168.33.180', 1024))
```

Here's the result of running the code on Linux:

```
python python/test.py 
(b'Z\xa5\x01\x00\x00\x00\xaa\xee', ('192.168.33.180', 4096))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python/test.py", line 19, in <module>
    recv = sock.recvfrom(4096)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Also, Wireshark output exported to .txt on Windows:

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      1 0.000000       192.168.33.30         192.168.33.180        UDP      50     4096 → 4096 Len=8

Frame 1: 50 bytes on wire (400 bits), 50 bytes captured (400 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{7D06A449-C87B-4FB9-98DE-A4257C349390}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: Micro-St_1a:f5:07 (30:9c:23:1a:f5:07), Dst: 0c:22:38:4e:5a:0c (0c:22:38:4e:5a:0c)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.33.30, Dst: 192.168.33.180
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 4096, Dst Port: 4096
Data (8 bytes)

0000  5a a5 01 00 00 00 aa ee                           Z.......

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      2 0.000053       192.168.33.180        192.168.33.30         UDP      60     1024 → 4096 Len=8

Frame 2: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{7D06A449-C87B-4FB9-98DE-A4257C349390}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: 0c:22:38:4e:5a:0c (0c:22:38:4e:5a:0c), Dst: Micro-St_1a:f5:07 (30:9c:23:1a:f5:07)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.33.180, Dst: 192.168.33.30
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 1024, Dst Port: 4096
Data (8 bytes)

0000  5a a5 01 00 00 00 aa ee                           Z.......
```

And on Linux:

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     50 5.803244767    192.168.33.30         192.168.33.180        UDP      50     4096 → 4096 Len=8

Frame 50: 50 bytes on wire (400 bits), 50 bytes captured (400 bits) on interface enp53s0, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: d4:93:90:0b:da:18 (d4:93:90:0b:da:18), Dst: 0c:22:38:4e:5a:0c (0c:22:38:4e:5a:0c)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.33.30, Dst: 192.168.33.180
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 4096, Dst Port: 4096
Data (8 bytes)

0000  5a a5 01 00 00 00 aa ee                           Z.......

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     51 5.803624342    192.168.33.180        192.168.33.30         UDP      60     1024 → 4096 Len=8

Frame 51: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface enp53s0, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: 0c:22:38:4e:5a:0c (0c:22:38:4e:5a:0c), Dst: Micro-St_1a:f5:07 (30:9c:23:1a:f5:07)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.33.180, Dst: 192.168.33.30
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 1024, Dst Port: 4096
Data (8 bytes)

0000  5a a5 01 00 00 00 aa ee                           Z.......
```

Comment: Why don't you show the packet that is sent and received successfully and the one that doesn't work?

Comment: @user253751 I edited the post to show the packet contents.

Comment: I mean, you said you saw the packets in Wireshark. What did you see in Wireshark? Is there any difference between the Windows packet and the Linux packet?

Comment: Not the data in the packets, nor any of the header or data in the received packet. Some of the header stuff was different in the sent packet but that's probably some sequence data and it shouldn't matter since the received packet was the same.